# SQL : variable inclusif or all

Tags: sql, variables, case

I have a SQL variable `@devise` that could be (null, 0 or 1)

It can be declared like this:

```
DECLARE @devise AS integer = NULL;
DECLARE @devise AS integer = 0;
DECLARE @devise AS integer = 1;
```

If `@devise` is null, I should get all data whether the column `InReceivableOffset` is equal to 0 or 1

```
AND InReceivableOffset = (CASE WHEN @devise = NULL THEN myAllcomment ELSE @devise END)
```

If my variable `@devise` is equal to 0 or 1 it works but what should be `myAllcomment` if `@devise` is null in my Case statement ?

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: You should **never** check for `= null` - **always** use `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
AND InReceivableOffset = coalesce(@devise, InReceivableOffset)
```